# Rails & Heroku: How to Implement Twitter Streaming API in background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter, streaming

I'm using the [Twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem to process tweets from the Twitter streaming API and save them to my DB.

But how do I implement the background process that's always running on Heroku? I've searched around the web and can't find any resources.

Do I just set a twitter.rb in config/initializers that sets up the streaming client? How do I keep that as a background process?

Comment: We use a "worker process" on heroku to run our background jobs. From your command line you can run `heroku ps` and see the current processes running for your app. I'm not sure if you can have a worker process on the free tier but I believe you can have it on the one up from that. You can start your jobs using one of many rails background tools but personally I've found [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) to be the best. Does this really need to be a background job though? Perhaps its just better sorted during normal runtime. Without examples its hard to say if the load will be big enough.

Comment: [This heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) shows most of the information needed to run a background job on heroku.